# Как сделать такое меню? Динамическое, с фигурами на фоне

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu, graphics

Вообщем есть задача сделать такое меню [image: Это хэддер]

То-есть, какой должен быть функционал:
Если в админ панели добавят еще пункт меню, эти треугольники должны подстроится под него, если уберут - соответственно часть из них должна убраться.

Когда мы выбираем пункт меню, к нему должен прилипать еще треугольник, будто он активный. Вот так:

[image: Активный пункт меню]

Остальные должны затемнятся.

Подскажи, с помощью чего можно реализовать подобное, буду благодарен за детальное объяснение.

Comment: Привет, @Ind eec . Важно знать, адаптивным будет сайт или нет, от этого можно смотреть реализацию меню. Если адаптивный, то нужно увидеть мобильноt меню.

Comment: Вот тут еще 1 подводный камень, он должен быть максимально возможно адаптивным. 
И весь сайт будет построен с различной анимацией.

Comment: @Alexandrkazakov

Comment: @Ind eec Это сложное меню, у вас должны быть хорошие навыки вёрстки, чтобы его реализовать.
`он должен быть максимально возможно адаптивным.` - такого понятие нет, он адаптивный или нет. Должны быть макеты на адаптив.

Пока думаю так сделать:

1), Каждой кнопке задать фоновую картинку через nth-child. Через nth-child сделать фоновых картинок на большее количество пунктов, чем есть сейчас. Этим мы решим вопрос добавления большего количества пунктов в будущем.

2). Доп. треугольник сделать через например :before и показывать его при наведении.

Comment: "Под максимально возможно адаптивным" я имею ввиду: вплоть до моб. устройств, возможно ли реализовать такое меню.

Comment: @Ind eec Нужны фоновые треугольники в SVG и PNG форматах, попросите у дизайнера, что нарисовал данные картинки. Тогда можно думать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю вам может помочь библиотека D3.js. С ее помощью можно делать фантастические вещи, но есть проблема, что она требует уверенных знаний JS. Так же возможно реализовать на canvas